# How can i map data inside material ui card

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This is my code I am confused as to why nothing is returning as I am trying to map data from two apis. I think I will need two map functions as I am using two apis in order to get pictures from one api and facts from another.
I also want to add a button so that the user can click on the button for next random image and fact.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import './FactCard.css'
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import CardContent from '@mui/material/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@mui/material/CardMedia';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import { Button, CardActionArea, CardActions } from '@mui/material';

export default function MediaCard() {

    const [catPics, setCatPics] = useState([])
    const [catFacts, setCatFacts] = useState([])

    function fetchData(){
      
    const catPicsAPI = 'https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search'
    const catFactsAPI = 'https://catfact.ninja/fact'

    const getcatPics = axios.get(catPicsAPI)
    const getcatFacts = axios.get(catFactsAPI)
    axios.all([getcatPics, getcatFacts])
      .then(axios.spread((...allData) => {
        const allDataCat = allData[0].data
        const allDataCatFact = allData[1].data
        
        setCatPics(allDataCat)
        setCatFacts(allDataCatFact.fact)
        })
      )
    }
      
  
    useEffect(() => {
      fetchData()
    }, [])

  return (
    <>
    <div>
    <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
      <CardActionArea>
      {catPics.map((catPic) => {
        <CardMedia
          component="img"
          height="140"
          image={catPic.url}
          alt="green iguana"
        />
      })}
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
            Lizard
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
            {catFacts.map((catFact) => {
              <p>{catFact}</p>
            })}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size="small" color="primary">
          Share
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
    </div>
    </>
  );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning anything from your `Array.prototype.map`. Arrow functions [have implicit returns only when not using curly brackets / body braces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#comparing_traditional_functions_to_arrow_functions). You can safely leave them out (or use regular parenthesis `(` and `)` for better readability):

```
{catPics.map((catPic) =>
   <CardMedia
        component="img"
        height="140"
        image={catPic.url}
        alt="green iguana"
    />
)}

{catFacts.map((catFact) => <p>{catFact}</p> )}
```

Otherwise remember to add `return` instead:

```
{catPics.map((catPic) => {
    return <CardMedia
        component="img"
        height="140"
        image={catPic.url}
        alt="green iguana"
    />
})}

{catFacts.map((catFact) => {
     return <p>{catFact}</p>
})}
```